# Always stop the motor at the same position

Tags: relay, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, solid-state-relay

I asked this question 13 days ago [electronics.stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/608578/always-stop-the-motor-at-the-same-spot). DC motor has to stop always same spot. If we take the area where the motor starts to rotate as 0, the motor should always stop at 0 degrees, not 3 or 5 (until 1, 2 is okay I guess.)

They suggest me to use hall effect sensor. I run into this question in this link [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321801/arduino-program-to-use-hall-effect-sensor-stop-bldc-motor-at-the-same-position-e) . OP says it is not working.

OP says:
What I managed to do at this moment, is calibrate ESC through Arduino and also to brake immediately when the magnet reached the sensor after I kill the throttle. However, I cannot get the magnet to stop directly below the hall sensor.

I don't have any DC motor yet so I can't try but I will try it soon. What I want to ask is;

- In second link, OP couldn't manage to get this work with hall effect and magnet. IS there another way ?
- if I use switch for drive DC motor, I can instantly brake motor with connecting the positive and negative terminals of the motor. If I get feedback from hall sensor, maybe I can stop it with hard brake.
  So is it good idea to use relay for stopping dc motor when I get feedback from hall effect sensor ?

Here is a schematic:

[image]

Comment: Far too many questions that are quite frankly either too hand-wavy or pointing in different directions from each other. Focus down to a simpler question and don't try and cover everything in one go. Avoid asking questions that either solicit opinions or expect simple yes/no answers.

Comment: A brushless DC motor will always turn a bit further when you interrupt its power. That's due to physics; mass, momentum, etc. How much further it turns is due to its speed and "load" (i.e. the counter force of whatever the motor is turning) _at the moment of power interruption_. Only if you can guarantee that those parameters will always be the same, the motor will stop at the same point a bit further from the trigger point (i.e. your hall sensor/magnet combo). In some cases, that "bit further" is approaching zero. So, whether your approach works is completely application-dependent.

Comment: I'd just use a stepper motor; those are designed to stop at defined points, but require a bit more software complexity on your microcontroller.

Comment: I would just use a limit switch. Easier than a hall sensor

Comment: @ Andy aka , orithena and Ryan thank you for your comments. Ryan, I need to control this project with microcontroller and system has to work by itself so I musn't press button or anything. Still can I do that with limit switch ?